# How to Search all SQL tables & display rows in Multi-line text box?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have multiple SQL tables, which I use to populate data grid view and text boxes throughout my app. I would like to create a global search feature on the main page of the app to search all tables from a search box and display it in a textbox. I have no idea where to start. The textbox is to just view the details, no need to save, edit or delete. I currently have a search box and a search button and then a text box called `results`.

This is what I've got..

```vb
 Private Sub GlobalSearchbtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GlobalSearchbtn.Click
    Try
        conn.Open()
        Dim sql1 As String
        sql1 = "SELECT * from sys.objects where type like '" & txtGlobalsearch.Text & "%'"
        cmd = New SqlCommand(sql1, conn)
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
        While reader.Read
            txtresults.Text = reader(1).Tostring
        End While
        conn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you want to look for every varchar/nvarchar field in any table for the txtGlobalSearch.Text value ?

Comment: Yes, there shouldn't be many matches as the tables aren't extensive. Is it possible to display multiple table rows in a textbox? It really doesn't matter if it's formatted weirdly. Or is the only way using gridview?

Comment: Sincerely it's not that hard but I don't think it's a efficient way of doing things. I'm writing answer for you

Comment: I appreciate it! It's a feature that won't get used often, but if they can't find it using my navigation then it will prove that it's in there somewhere.

Comment: If they cant find it I would suggest looking at how you are setting up relations; primary/foreign keys/ constraints and such... Thats poor design and asking for issues down the road if you plan on doing anything with it. Why would you search the whole database anyways?

Comment: Also you tagged MySQL but in your code you are using SQL which one is it, they are different...

Comment: Oh i did sorry! What i mean is i want a quick search function where if they can't find it they can search it and it will display it in a basic format without tables etc.

Comment: If this is what you need, I would start designing metadata subsystem for your application. This metadata will represent information of all tables in your system, all fields, mark them searchable/not searchable, etc. This metadata could be used for many things besides search. Without searchable flag, it is going to be very inefficient, slow, resource intensive...

Answer (score -1):

You have to loop on all your tables present in your database. Then for each table you have to retrieve all the fields then select the varchar/nvarchar ones. Finaly you have to build a dynamic request to query the results on this field in this table.

I can't write you exactly what you have to do, but I can write you an example of an algorythm

```
var tableQuery = "SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE [FieldForTheTypeOfTheObject] = 'table'"
//execute and loop on each table
foreach table in tableQueryResult
    var fieldQuery = "SELECT * FROM [sys.objects or maybe another table] WHERE [FieldOfTheTypeOfTheObject] = 'field'"
    foreach field in fieldQueryResult
        if(field.Type == 'varchar' || field.Type == 'nvarchar') then
            var finalQuery = "SELECT * FROM " & table.Name & " WHERE " & field.Name & " like '%" & txtGlobalsearch.Text.Replace("'", "''") & "&'"
            //Execute  query and display data
        endif
    end
end
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the example. The FieldForTheTypeOfTheObject is that the column? or will it automatically be able to search all columns?

Comment: Sorry, i can't understand this code. Please forgive me i'm very new to vb.net. Could you simplify? is this in vb.net?

What is the fieldforthetypeofobject supposed to be?

Comment: Sorry i'm using MS SQL, i tagged it incorrectly. my apologies!